# Issue while trying to verify signature

Tags: solidity, web3js, signature

I am using the following to sign a message

```
 var str="Trial with signature";
 text=web3.sha3(str);
 var sig=web3.eth.sign(eth.accounts[0],text);
```

Now after obtaining the hash value from the text and the signature, to verify the same, I use the following contract

```
contract signature
{
    event ret_addr(address addr);
    function sig_verify(bytes32 hash, bytes sig) returns(address)                       //verifying the signature
    {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;
        assembly 
        {
                r := mload(add(sig, 32))
                s := mload(add(sig, 64))
                v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
            }
        if(v<27)
            v+=27;
        ret_addr(ecrecover(hash, v, r, s));
    }
}
```

The issue is I am not getting the correct address back. Why is this so? It used to work fine earlier but now it is giving some random addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [workflow on signing a string with private key, followed by signature verification with public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio)

Comment: Although, that answer focuses on breaking up the signature in javascript, while this one is trying to break up the pieces within a solidity contract, so I don't feel like they're the same thing.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Your code here is working fine as-is for me...

Comment: Should be `mload(add(sig, 65))` instead of `mload(add(sig, 96))` and see answer below about `Ethereum Signed Message`prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add a prefix to the data as discussed in [issue #3731](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731):

```
bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
hash = sha3(prefix, hash);
```

Related

- [Getting the wrong address back from ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover/12684)
- [workflow on signing a string with private key, followed by signature verification with public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/30324)
- [I need help with signatures](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/i-need-help-with-signatures)
- [Does ecRecover in solidity expects the "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"-prefix](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/does-ecrecover-in-solidity-expects-the-x19ethereum-signed-message-n-prefix/21037)
- [Should signed text messages use the "\x19Ethereum Signed Message" prefix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/should-signed-text-messages-use-the-x19ethereum-signed-message-prefix/30173)
- [Totally baffled by ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/totally-baffled-by-ecrecover/30445)

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with `assembly` section. You can debug by extending your event like this

```
event ret_addr(address addr, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s);
```

and call it with corrwsponding variables

```
ret_addr(ecrecover(hash, v, r, s), v, r, s);
```

My result:

```
[
    {
        "topic": "1171b064e2eda38d82ce5fadc8a911d493f2d22ff88013d965c9885638dee60d",
        "event": "ret_addr",
        "args": [
            "0x0",
            "97",
            "0x3078613963356435666332336333663762313130313134313262663536366432",
            "0x3638333437353534666561666665333164363662343539383739373435373562"
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, `v` is neither `27` nor `28`. `r` and `s` are not hex encoded but with `0x` prefix.