# Does ecRecover in solidity expects the "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"-prefix

Tags: solidity, ecrecover

I struggle heavy to actually recover the ethereum address from a hash and the `{r, s, v}` from a signature with the `ecRecover`-method in solidity.

What i want is to sign another ethereum-address. So i hash that address with sha3 and hex-encoding in web3, and sign it with my address. I then extract {r, s, v} from it and call my method. But i never get the correct result.

```
    function recover(bytes32 _h, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s){
    ecRecovery = ecrecover(_h, _v, _r, _s);
}
```

The address i want to sign is: `0x8CbaC5e4d803bE2A3A5cd3DbE7174504c6DD0c1C`

The resulting hash for it for me is: `0x4d55361a8f362c8fc244dbd1e4968ca4b96d58e63a0f0c01a2cad1149106568a`

After signing it, i get: `0x7709ac9c45926cc4d9791d868ad6c81883b624db44fbae1e62c0e6cc6c19784b74eb7f5ecdcf33f9c61946dc33b57964b1a0fee40ebf3b9c875424553cb865031b`

From which i extract:

`v = 27
r = 7709ac9c45926cc4d9791d868ad6c81883b624db44fbae1e62c0e6cc6c19784b
s = 74eb7f5ecdcf33f9c61946dc33b57964b1a0fee40ebf3b9c875424553cb86503`

feeding that into my function, i get: `0x9a5aAF102C82FaB302923bF8838678728A520103`
whis is wrong. What i expect is:
`0x1b7fBea9e926B1eAfC299b9Fab8f7174f466244e`

My first instinct was to add the prefix of "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", but that doesn't work either. Probably because i'm doing it wrong. So, is anybody able to help me with that one?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio

Answer (score 16):

According to [issue #3731](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731):

> Geth prepends the string `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n<length of message>` to all data before signing it (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign). If you want to verify such a signature from Solidity, you'll have to prepend the same string in solidity before doing the ecrecovery.

Here's a working example I tested out using [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/):

Example.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Example {
    function testRecovery(bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (address) {
        bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
        bytes32 prefixedHash = sha3(prefix, h);
        address addr = ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);

        return addr;
    }
}
```

example.js (test)

```
var Example = artifacts.require('./Example.sol')

var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

contract('Example', (accounts) => {
  var address = accounts[0]

  it('ecrecover result matches address', async function() {
    var instance = await Example.deployed()
    var msg = '0x8CbaC5e4d803bE2A3A5cd3DbE7174504c6DD0c1C'

    var h = web3.sha3(msg)
    var sig = web3.eth.sign(address, h).slice(2)
    var r = `0x${sig.slice(0, 64)}`
    var s = `0x${sig.slice(64, 128)}`
    var v = web3.toDecimal(sig.slice(128, 130)) + 27

    var result = await instance.testRecovery.call(h, v, r, s)
    assert.equal(result, address)
  })
})
```

Running test:

```
$ truffle test

Using network 'development'.

Compiling ./contracts/Example.sol...


  Contract: Example
    ✓ ecrecover result matches address (132ms)


  1 passing (147ms)
```

It's probably better to do the prefixing at the application level instead of in solidity contract since it'll be cheaper.

Related

- [Getting the wrong address back from ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover/12684)
- [Should signed text messages use the "\x19Ethereum Signed Message" prefix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/should-signed-text-messages-use-the-x19ethereum-signed-message-prefix/30173)
- [workflow on signing a string with private key, followed by signature verification with public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/30324)
- [I need help with signatures](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/i-need-help-with-signatures/19711#19711)
- [Totally baffled by ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/totally-baffled-by-ecrecover/30445)

Comment: The web3.eth.sign function seems to take msg as first parameter and the address as second parameter now. See this answer if you are running into errors ->https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40837/31604