# Getting an address from ethereumjs-utils ecrecover

Tags: signature, cryptography, ethereumjs, ecrecover

I am trying to sign a string using web3.eth.sign() and then get the public key I signed with from the signature. To do this I am using ecrecover() from ethereumjs-utils, which returns a buffer. When I use bufferToHex() on the buffer it gives a hex string that is much too long to be an address - 130 characters including '0x'

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(myAccount,pass)
msg = web3.sha3(aString)
sig = web3.eth.sign(myAccount,msg)
r = sig.slice(0, 66)
s = '0x' + sig.slice(66, 130)
v = '0x' + sig.slice(130, 132)
v = web3.toDecimal(v)
msg = ethJsUtil.toBuffer(msg)
addr = ethJsUtil.ecrecover(msg,v,r,s)
addr = ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(addr)
```

I took most of the code from the answer to [workflow on signing a string with private key, followed by signature verification with public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio) but had to convert 'msg' to a buffer as ecrecover threw a type error otherwise.

What do I need to do to convert the buffer from ecrecover to an address?

Comment: Which OS your on? also you used Meteor ?

Comment: I am on macOS Sierra and yes this is using meteor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`ecrecover`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/modules/_signature_.md#const-ecrecover) returns *public key*, you need to convert it to address with [`pubToAddress`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/modules/_account_.md#const-pubtoaddress).

```
pub     = ethJsUtil.ecrecover(msg, v, r, s);
addrBuf = ethJsUtil.pubToAddress(pub);
addr    = ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(addrBuf);
```

Also, you can use [`fromRpcSig`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/modules/_signature_.md#const-fromrpcsig) to get `v, r, s`

```
sig = web3.eth.sign(myAccount,msg)
res = ethJsUtil.fromRpcSig(sig)
pub = ethJsUtil.ecrecover(msg, res.v, res.r, res.s);
```

Please note that `web3.eth.sign` adds prefix to the message before signing it (see [JSON-RPC spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign)).

Here is how to add it manually:

```
const util = require('ethereumjs-util')

const msg = new Buffer('hello');
const sig = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], '0x' + msg.toString('hex'));
const res = util.fromRpcSig(sig);

const prefix = new Buffer("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n");
const prefixedMsg = util.sha3(
  Buffer.concat([prefix, new Buffer(String(msg.length)), msg])
);

const pubKey  = util.ecrecover(prefixedMsg, res.v, res.r, res.s);
const addrBuf = util.pubToAddress(pubKey);
const addr    = util.bufferToHex(addrBuf);

console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0],  addr);
```

---

On the other hand, testrpc (at least version 3.0.5) does not add such prefix.

Example node.js + testrpc session:

```
const util = require('ethereumjs-util')

const msg = web3.sha3('hello!');
const sig = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], msg);
const {v, r, s} = util.fromRpcSig(sig);

const pubKey  = util.ecrecover(util.toBuffer(msg), v, r, s);
const addrBuf = util.pubToAddress(pubKey);
const addr    = util.bufferToHex(addrBuf);

console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0], addr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the pubToAddress is definitely what I was looking for but it is not giving the same address as the one I signed with. Do you have any idea why this might be or should I mark this answer as correct and make a new question?

Comment: Everything should be ok. I updated my answer with example session. There might be a problem with `v, r, s` recovery, try to use `fromRpcSig`.

Comment: I copy pasted your demo code and still get different addresses when I use it.

Comment: I cant see why this would make any difference but I had to use the line var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")) instead of your lines 2- 4 as it couldn't find the module

Comment: What versions of web3.js and ethereumjs-util you are using? Btw, I think now this deserves separate question.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover

Answer (score 0):

Example node.js + ethereumjs-util other method to validate signature

```js
const ethUtil = require("ethereumjs-util");

const inSignature = "0x...."; //user signed message
const message = "hello!";
const msgHex = ethUtil.bufferToHex(Buffer.from(message));
const msgBuffer = ethUtil.toBuffer(msgHex);
const msgHash = ethUtil.hashPersonalMessage(msgBuffer);

const signature = ethUtil.toBuffer(inSignature);

const sigParams = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(signature);
const publicKey = ethUtil.ecrecover(
            msgHash,
            sigParams.v,
            sigParams.r,
            sigParams.s
);

const sender = ethUtil.publicToAddress(publicKey);
const addr = ethUtil.bufferToHex(sender);

//now compare addr with user wallet address
if("0x<userWaller>" === addr) console.log("valid");
```