# How to use web3 function (ecRecover) that shouldn't require a provider?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers, ecrecover

I want to use web3's `ecRecover` functionality and nothing else. Unless I misunderstand its requirements -  a signature, the signed data, some cryptomagic and poof you have recovered the signer - why do I need to have a provider for it? What I'm trying to say is that this functionality could be implemented without relying on the RPC connection. So is there a way to do `ecRecover` in Node.js or even vanilla javascript sans web3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a provider. If web3.js won't let you use ecrecover without one for some reason or you prefer something more lightweight, take a look at ethereumjs-util:

https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md

See the answer to this question for an example:
[Getting an address from ethereumjs-utils ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12571/getting-an-address-from-ethereumjs-utils-ecrecover)

Comment: Awesome! But I only have the signature hex. Is there a way I can figure out the v, r, s arguments?

Comment: Spoke too soon. Got it. Appreciate your help.