# Ecrecover after eth_sign update with preamble

Tags: go-ethereum, signature, recovery, sha3, keccak

I've just discovered that with b59c839 geth is now pre-appending the string:

```
*\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n<length of message>*
```

before signing the passed message. [I've read here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731) that to use ecrecover on Soldity side it must be pre-appended the same string on the contract. 
Do you have any working example on how to correctly manage this pre-appending on a Solidity contract?

Thank you

----- ----- ----- UPDATE

I'm trying to pre-append the signature locally in **geth** with something like this:

```
test = web3.sha3("hello")
eth.sign(eth.accounts[0], test)
hash_preamble = web3.sha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + test.length + test)
```

Then on the contract side I'm trying to test something as simple as this:

```
function test(bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v, bytes32 hash_preamble) constant returns (address) {
    address signer = ecrecover(hash_preamble, v, r, s);
    return signer;
}
```

The *`bytes32`* values passed to the contract are in the form of "0x1234" while the *`uint8`* is 27 or 28. The hash passed to the contract is the composed hash with the preamble, length of my message (which is an hash) and my message.

Unfortunately I'm not able to get the same address as the signing one. Can you see some mistakes in my code?

Comment: Do you really need to do the prepending on the solidity side? It will be quite complicated and expensive. It would be far easier to just pass in the message with the prefix already attached.

Comment: Yeah right, it can actually be done like that! Thanks you! What's the exact string to append and how if the value to be signed is the digest hashed_messages = web3.Sha3(first message, second message) ? :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stumped on this myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any working example on how to correctly manage this pre-appending on a Solidity contract?

You can check out the Etherdelta smart contract https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol

```
function availableVolume(address tokenGet, uint amountGet, address tokenGive, uint amountGive, uint expires, uint nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(uint) {
    bytes32 hash = sha256(this, tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce);
    if (!(
      (orders[user][hash] || ecrecover(sha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash),v,r,s) == user) &&
      block.number <= expires
    )) return 0;
    uint available1 = safeSub(amountGet, orderFills[user][hash]);
    uint available2 = safeMul(tokens[tokenGive][user], amountGet) / amountGive;
    if (available1<available2) return available1;
    return available2;
  }
```

Here the signed message is `hash` with size 32. Note that they use `sha256` to create the message which costs more gas than `sha3`, I suspect they did it for compatibility with the client side.

`ecrecover` is described in [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) with example usage:

> ecrecover(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (address):
>   recover the address associated with the public key from elliptic curve signature or return zero on error ([example usage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio))

You can see more examples in different languages on Github: https://github.com/search?l=&q=%5Cx19Ethereum+Signed+Message&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

---

From your bounty note:

> provide a way to recover the original message from the signed message hash such that the integrity of h can be verified

It's not possible to recover the original message from the hash. All the `ecrecover` can do is to "recover the address associated with the public key from elliptic curve signature or return zero on error". It basically tells you whether the signature belongs to the given address.