# ecrecover from Geth and web3.eth.sign

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, cryptography, ecrecover

I have tried to use `ecrecover()` to verify the signature of a message.

I have looked at lots of references here and elsewhere, like:

- https://lab-blog.ey.com/2016/12/19/ecrecover/
- [How does one properly use ecrecover to verify Ethereum signatures?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/how-does-one-properly-use-ecrecover-to-verify-ethereum-signatures)
- [Ethereum ecrecover signature verification and encryption](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/ethereum-ecrecover-signature-verification-and-encryption)

and others.

But I still cannot get `ecrecover()` to return the signing address. So I am hoping that someone can point out some stupid mistake I am making.

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract test {

  function test() {
  }

  function verify(bytes32 _message, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) constant returns (address) {
   address signer = ecrecover(_message, _v, _r, _s);
   return signer;
  }
}
```

---

Then in geth, I do:

```
> var msg = web3.sha3("hello")
"0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"

> eth.accounts[0] -->
"0x7156526fbd7a3c72969b54f64e42c10fbb768c8a"

> var sig = eth.sign(eth.accounts[0], msg)
"0x9242685bf161793cc25603c231bc2f568eb630ea16aa137d2664ac80388256084f8ae3bd7535248d0bd448298cc2e2071e56992d0774dc340c368ae950852ada1c"

> var r = sig.substr(0,66)
"0x9242685bf161793cc25603c231bc2f568eb630ea16aa137d2664ac8038825608"

> var s = "0x" + sig.substr(66,64)
"0x4f8ae3bd7535248d0bd448298cc2e2071e56992d0774dc340c368ae950852ada"

> var v = 28
28

> test.verify(msg,v,r,s)
"0x33692ee5cbf7ecdb8ca43ec9e815c47f3db8cd11"
```

...which of course, is NOT `eth.accounts[0]`

I am totally stumped. Is there anyone who can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your first link has died... :-(

Comment: The given solution does not work in remix compiler version 0.5.8.
Please help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35665)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35665)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I was stuck on this issue as well for a very long time.

So the solution is: Add this prefix string to your Solidity smart contract.

```
function verify(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(bool) {

    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(prefix, hash);
    return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s) == (Your Address);
}
```

Comment: dude, you nailed it! Thanks! I do not totally understand what is going on there or why it works like that, but it definitely works... There is a question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/ecrecover-after-eth-sign-update-with-preamble)  about whether you can pass in the preamble already hashed, rather than doing it in Solidity.. do you have a view on that? Anyway, nice one! Thanks again!

Comment: omg, in case anybody else is random guessing like me: the `32` at the end of the `prefix` corresponds to the message length! https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign

Comment: @AdilHaris `Add this prefix string to your Solidity smart contract` and [in the case I do not control the smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49299/25002)?

Comment: Small, but clear article - http://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3

Answer (score 15):

According to [issue #3731](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731):

> Geth prepends the string `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n<length of message>` to all data before signing it (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign). If you want to verify such a signature from Solidity, you'll have to prepend the same string in solidity before doing the ecrecovery.

Here's a working example I tested out using [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/):

Example.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Example {
    function testRecovery(bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns (address) {
        bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
        bytes32 prefixedHash = sha3(prefix, h);
        address addr = ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);

        return addr;
    }
}
```

example.js (test)

```
var Example = artifacts.require('./Example.sol')

var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

contract('Example', (accounts) => {
  var address = accounts[0]

  it('ecrecover result matches address', async function() {
    var instance = await Example.deployed()
    var msg = '0x8CbaC5e4d803bE2A3A5cd3DbE7174504c6DD0c1C'

    var h = web3.sha3(msg)
    var sig = web3.eth.sign(address, h).slice(2)
    var r = `0x${sig.slice(0, 64)}`
    var s = `0x${sig.slice(64, 128)}`
    var v = web3.toDecimal(sig.slice(128, 130)) + 27

    var result = await instance.testRecovery.call(h, v, r, s)
    assert.equal(result, address)
  })
})
```

Running test:

```
$ truffle test

Using network 'development'.

Compiling ./contracts/Example.sol...


  Contract: Example
    ✓ ecrecover result matches address (132ms)


  1 passing (147ms)
```

It's probably better to do the prefixing at the application level instead of in solidity contract since it'll be cheaper.

Related

- [Getting the wrong address back from ecrecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover/12684)
- [Should signed text messages use the "\x19Ethereum Signed Message" prefix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/should-signed-text-messages-use-the-x19ethereum-signed-message-prefix/30173)
- [workflow on signing a string with private key, followed by signature verification with public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/30324)
- [I need help with signatures](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19685/i-need-help-with-signatures/19711#19711)

Comment: Does the value '0x8CbaC5e4d803bE2A3A5cd3DbE7174504c6DD0c1C' that you assigned to the msg variable have any significance?  Or is it just dummy data for the call?  In other words, is it just something for the sha3() function to hash?

Also, why do you need to use the slice() function on the hash with a  2 byte offset?  Is it to get ride of the format identifier in the hash?

Comment: @RobertOschler great questions. 1. It's best practice to hash the message data to sign because it's always the same size. The msg value in the example is an example of a hash, eg sha3("some data to sign"). 2. Yes, it's to remove the 0x prefix which aren't important bytes that are required for the calculation

Answer (score 7):

So, with thanks to [Adil](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/8156/adil-haris) (see above), here is the finished code that I used that definitely works with the process as outlined by me above:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract test {

  function test() {
  }

  function verify(bytes32 _message, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) constant returns (address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = sha3(prefix, _message);
    address signer = ecrecover(prefixedHash, _v, _r, _s);
    return signer;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am totally confused by this. In your example contract the _message is the hash you really sign on, right? I mean the _message is the message your sign on and generate the _v, _r and _s. Then in the contract you hash it the second time with the prefix and throw it into the ecrecover function, right? Why we need to do like this and it seems to me doesn't work.(I generate the _r, _s, _v in Truffle and test the contract in Remix) Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: yes, that is exactly how it works.. you hash a message and pass it into the contract. Then you hash it again with the prefix. Then it works. But I don't know why it works. I cannot help you further than that, except to say that if you follow they above steps you should get the right answer. If anyone could explain why this works, or why you even need that random prefix, that would be great!

Comment: with go-ethereum you'll need `v+27` instead. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2053

Comment: `v+27` fails where i've seen , but somebody use it  for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the right data types?
I've created a simple validation app using ecrecover a few weeks ago.

You can watch the code here: https://github.com/Shultzi/validator/blob/master/client/main.js

As you can see, I passed the `h`, `r` and `s` not as `buffers` but a `hex`.
Also, make sure that in your smart contract the `v` value is `uint8`

Comment: BTW, I just checked your arguments in my code and I also received the address "0x3369..." I'm certain that it has something to do with the account you're signing. Which client you're using for signing?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply... I am signing via the geth console. Using version 1.6.1-stable-021c3c28 of geth and doing web3.eth.sign() . You think there is a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

The following article may explain the "\x19EthereumSignedMessage" part

https://blog.ricmoo.com/verifying-messages-in-solidity-50a94f82b2ca

Comment: The way OpenZeppelin's ECDSA does it is to require that you hash your message into a bytes32, rather than using evm assembly to generate a base10 string representing the arbitrary length of the message string.

Answer (score 0):

OpenZeppelin's ECDSA has a tool to generate these wrapped messages as well as root out additional corner cases in ECDSA.

I wrote an article describing what I think is the right way to use web3's hashMessage() and sign(), Solidity's ecrecover(), and Open Zeppelin's ECDSA lib.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/cryptography/ECDSA.sol

https://medium.com/@yaoshiang/ethereums-ecrecover-openzeppelin-s-ecdsa-and-web3-s-sign-8ff8d16595e1