# Recover address from signature using web3j

Tags: web3js, web3j, signature

I have signed a data string using the following code snippet in **web3js**

```
var data = "hello world";

web3.personal.sign(web3.fromUtf8(data), web3.eth.accounts[0], function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Now I am trying to verify the address used to sign said string  from **web3j**

```
public static boolean verifyAddressFromSignature(String address, String signature) 
{
    byte[] signatureBytes = Hash.sha3(signature).getBytes();
    byte v = signatureBytes[64];
    if(v < 27) 
    { 
        v += 27; 
    }

    SignatureData sd = new SignatureData(v, (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 0, 32), (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 32, 64));

    String addressRecovered = null;
    boolean match = false;

    // Iterate for each possible key to recover
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        BigInteger publicKey = Sign.recoverFromSignature((byte) i, new ECDSASignature(new BigInteger(1, sd.getR()), new BigInteger(1, sd.getS())), signature.getBytes());

        if (publicKey != null) 
        {
            addressRecovered = "0x" + Keys.getAddress(publicKey); 
            System.out.println(addressRecovered);
            if (addressRecovered.equals(address)) 
            {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

However, none of the generated addresses match the one used to create the signature.

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're taking the `sha3` of some sort of string representation of the signature?

Comment: Does something from here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17708/solidity-ecrecover-and-web3j-sign-signmessage-are-not-compatible-is-it will help you?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation I wrote that works exactly like the JavaScript `ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message, signature)` and `ethers.utils.recoverAddress(digest, signature)` methods.

*EthersUtils.java*

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.web3j.crypto.ECDSASignature;
import org.web3j.crypto.Hash;
import org.web3j.crypto.Keys;
import org.web3j.crypto.Sign;
import org.web3j.crypto.Sign.SignatureData;
import org.web3j.utils.Numeric;

public class EthersUtils {
  private static final String MESSAGE_PREFIX = "\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n";

  public static String verifyMessage(String message, String signature) {
    return EthersUtils.recoverAddress(EthersUtils.hashMessage(message), signature);
  }

  public static String hashMessage(String message) {
    return Hash.sha3(
        Numeric.toHexStringNoPrefix(
            (EthersUtils.MESSAGE_PREFIX + message.length() + message).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
  }

  public static String recoverAddress(String digest, String signature) {
    SignatureData signatureData = EthersUtils.getSignatureData(signature);
    int header = 0;
    for (byte b : signatureData.getV()) {
      header = (header << 8) + (b & 0xFF);
    }
    if (header < 27 || header > 34) {
      return null;
    }
    int recId = header - 27;
    BigInteger key = Sign.recoverFromSignature(
        recId,
        new ECDSASignature(
            new BigInteger(1, signatureData.getR()), new BigInteger(1, signatureData.getS())),
        Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(digest));
    if (key == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return ("0x" + Keys.getAddress(key)).trim();
  }

  private static SignatureData getSignatureData(String signature) {
    byte[] signatureBytes = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(signature);
    byte v = signatureBytes[64];
    if (v < 27) {
      v += 27;
    }
    byte[] r = (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 0, 32);
    byte[] s = (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 32, 64);
    return new SignatureData(v, r, s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package org.web3j.crypto;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.web3j.crypto.Sign.SignatureData;
import org.web3j.utils.Numeric;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class ECRecoverTest {

    public static final String PERSONAL_MESSAGE_PREFIX = "\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n";

    @Test
    public void testRecoverAddressFromSignature() {

        String signature =
                "0x2c6401216c9031b9a6fb8cbfccab4fcec6c951cdf40e2320108d1856eb532250576865fbcd452bcdc4c57321b619ed7a9cfd38bd973c3e1e0243ac2777fe9d5b1b";

        String address = "0x31b26e43651e9371c88af3d36c14cfd938baf4fd";
        String message = "v0G9u7huK4mJb2K1";

        String prefix = PERSONAL_MESSAGE_PREFIX + message.length();
        byte[] msgHash = Hash.sha3((prefix + message).getBytes());

        byte[] signatureBytes = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(signature);
        byte v = signatureBytes[64];
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }

        SignatureData sd =
                new SignatureData(
                        v,
                        (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 0, 32),
                        (byte[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 32, 64));

        String addressRecovered = null;
        boolean match = false;

        // Iterate for each possible key to recover
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            BigInteger publicKey =
                    Sign.recoverFromSignature(
                            (byte) i,
                            new ECDSASignature(
                                    new BigInteger(1, sd.getR()), new BigInteger(1, sd.getS())),
                            msgHash);

            if (publicKey != null) {
                addressRecovered = "0x" + Keys.getAddress(publicKey);

                if (addressRecovered.equals(address)) {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        assertEquals(addressRecovered, (address));
        assertTrue(match);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/test/java/org/web3j/crypto/ECRecoverTest.java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What are these 4 keys its iterating through? is it always 4?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to verify the signature without providing what the message was which was hashed.. this is one more param you need to provide