# Hash a message in ethereum-js and check in Solidity

Tags: solidity, javascript, hash-algorithm

I'm trying to check an hashed message inside my Solidity smart contract. In JavaScript I hash the message as follows:

```
util.sha3(Buffer.concat([
  new Buffer(address1),
  new Buffer(bytes32),
  new Buffer("0"),
  new Buffer(address2),
  new Buffer("0")
])).toString("hex");
```

When I check in Solidity I do

```
keccak256(id,ca,dataHash, false, address(0), false);
```

I've tried both with `keccak256` and `sha3`, but both yield a different hash than the one produced in JavaScript. I'm suspecting some encoding issue (probably due to `Buffer` doing something different than Solidity), but I can't find anything about that.

Note that I'm not signing anything, so the issue described in this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/ecrecover-from-geth-and-web3-eth-sign) should not apply (at least, not as I understand the answer and documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had three issues, mostly related to JavaScript and not, as I assumed in the question, with Solidity. For anyone who will encounter the same problem in the future, I list them here:

First of all, on the JS side, `sha3` takes one or more `Buffer`s as an input, which by default decode strings as utf-8, while web3.js decodes the same strings as hexes when sending them to the smart contract. The quickest way to solve this was to truncate the strings to remove the `0x` part and change the encoding from Buffer:

```
Buffer.from(mystring.substring(2), "hex")
```

But after that my tests kept failing. Two of my values were booleans, which meant that I tried to have a Buffer of a single bit. This doesn't seem possible with Buffer, since anything shorter than a byte will be ignored. Luckily, `0x00` and `0x01` work as well for `false` and `true`, so I had to change my bool's encoding to:

```
Buffer.from("00", "hex")
```

Which output is hashed in the same way as `false` in Solidity (the same works with `"01"` and `true`)

Still, my *automated* tests kept failing. This was because `util.sha3` yields a Buffer, which `toString` method returns a string like `0x1234567890abcdef`, but web3.js' calls return a string without the first two charactes (like `1234567890abcdef`).