# Trouble with ecrecover()

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, javascript, ecrecover

I have a test routine in Truffle which hashes data, signs it and passes the signature data to a contract to verify.  The first test hashes a single string and its signature is successfully verified by the contract.  The second hashes a number and an address.  This second test fails as `ecrecover()` does not return `msg.sender`.

The contract I am testing is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ContractAuth {
    function getPrefixedHash(bytes32 messageHash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes memory hashPrefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(hashPrefix, messageHash));
    } 

    // https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15911
    function verifyMessageHash(bytes32 messageHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 prefixedHash = getPrefixedHash(messageHash);
        return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s) == msg.sender;
    }
}
```

In order to keep the above functions internal, I have created a test wrapper contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./ContractAuth .sol";

// TestContractAuth acts as a wrapper contract, allowing internal and
// private functions to be accessed without modifying the scope of the actual functions.
contract TestContractAuth is ContractAuth {

    // Test access to ContractAuth::getPrefixedHash()
    function getPrefixedHashTest(bytes32 messageHash) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return getPrefixedHash(messageHash);
    }

    // Test access to ContractAuth::verifyMessageHash()
    function verifyMessageHashTest(bytes32 messageHash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public view returns (bool) {
        return verifyMessageHash(messageHash, v, r, s);
    }

    function verifyMultipleInputs(uint256 inputNumber, address inputAddress, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(inputNumber, inputAddress));
        return verifyMessageHash(messageHash, v, r, s);
    }
}
```

The tests routine for verifying signed data is as follows:

```
it("verify signed data", async () => {
    // getInstance() deploys the test contract above and returns
    // an instance to it for testing
    const contractAuth = getInstance("TestContractAuth");
    const testAddr = await web3.eth.getCoinbase();
    const msgPrefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";

    {
        let hashedMessage = web3.utils.soliditySha3("Hello, World!");
        const prefixedHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(msgPrefix, hashedMessage);

        let rawSig = await web3.eth.sign(prefixedHash, testAddr);
        const sig = parseSignature(rawSig);

        let validSig =
            await contractAuth.methods.verifyMessageHashTest(prefixedHash, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s).call();

        assert.equal(validSig, true, "Expected valid signature returned by verifyMessageHashTest()");
    }
    {   // Test currently fails...
        // TODO: ask question on StackExchange

        let price = 100000000;
        let contractAddr = "0x856F6BD97c2e74F1089a9e7827586a8E3447400b";

        let hashedMessage = web3.utils.soliditySha3(price, contractAddr);
        const prefixedHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(msgPrefix, hashedMessage);

        const rawSig = await web3.eth.sign(prefixedHash, testAddr);
        const sig = parseSignature(rawSig);

        let validSig =
            await contractAuth.methods.verifyMultipleInputs(price, contractAddr, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s).call();

        assert.equal(validSig, true, "expected valid sig from verifyMultipleInputs()");
    }
});
```

`parseSignature()` is a helper function to perform the slicing of the raw signature returned by `web3.eth.sign()`.

The first `assert.equal()` call passes as the signature is successfully verified on the contract.  The second fails and currently I do not know why.

My belief is that there is an issue in the format of `inputNumber` and `inputAddress` when I hash it in the client.  Is there a way this data should be formatted before it is hashed?

---

**Edit0:**

In order to verify hashing, I have added the following function to my test contract:

```
function hashMultipleValues(uint256 inputNumber, address inputAddress) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(inputNumber, inputAddress));
}
```

Which simply returns the hashed combination of the two inputs.

I have added the following to a test in order to verify hashes side-by-side:

```
let hashedMessage = web3.utils.soliditySha3(price, contractAddr);
let solHashedMessage =
    await contractAuth.methods.hashMultipleValues(price, contractAddr).call();
console.log("Solidity:\t" + solHashedMessage);
console.log("Web3:\t\t" + hashedMessage);
```

With the given input values above, I get the following output in the console during the test:

```
Solidity:       0xdce71017994de76c5339d7b083bcbe948e6e75786de1faeb971c2cb369913535
Web3:           0xdce71017994de76c5339d7b083bcbe948e6e75786de1faeb971c2cb369913535
```

This proves that there's parity between the methods of hashing that I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I appear to have stumbled upon the answer.  The issue I had was that I was signing the prefixed message, rather than just the hash without the prefix.

The modified test, which calls `verifyMultipleInputs()` on my test contract, appears as follows:

```
const testAddr = await web3.eth.getCoinbase();
let price = 100000000;
let contractAddr = "0x856F6BD97c2e74F1089a9e7827586a8E3447400b";

let hashedMessage = web3.utils.soliditySha3(price, contractAddr);

// Sign the hashedMessage, not a prefixedHash
const rawSig = await web3.eth.sign(hashedMessage, testAddr);
const sig = parseSignature(rawSig);

let validSig =
    await CentraDEX.methods.verifyMultipleInputs(price, contractAddr, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s).call({from: testAddr});

assert.equal(validSig, true, "expected valid sig from verifyMultipleInputs()");
```

The function on the contract is now returning true and the test passes.  Can someone explain why I *shouldn't* be signing prefixed data before calling the contract?

**Edit0:**

`geth` prepends the `Ethereum Signed Message` internally when sign is called.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/b59c8399fbe42390a3d41e945d03b1f21c1a9b8d

Comment: btw, you should edit your question other than put the content in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to make sure that the `msg.sender` when calling smart contract function is expected

change:

```
let validSig =
    await contractAuth.methods.verifyMultipleInputs(price, contractAddr, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s).call();
```

to:

```
let validSig =
    await contractAuth.methods.verifyMultipleInputs(price, contractAddr, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s).call({from: testAddr});
```

And the problem may come from `abi.encodePacked`; so these two below are difference

`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(inputNumber, inputAddress)`

and

`web3.utils.soliditySha3(price, contractAddr);`

It may give warning, but you can try to use `keccak256(inputNumber, inputAddress)` to confirm the problem.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but that addition has not fixed the issue for me.  It _is_ an addition that I will keep in the tests to ensure I'm sending from that test address.

Comment: okay, note that `keccak256` and `sha3` is not the same hash algorithm

Comment: I thought the point of `soliditySha3()` was to mimic the behaviour of `keccak256()`?

Comment: oh, okay! my bad. So the problem may come from the `abi.encodePacked`