# Public key validation through private key

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, private-key

What is a good way to validate that the public key claimed to belong to a particular user really belongs to him without revealing the associated private key? Can this be done with zero-knowledge proofs? or is there a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask them to sign a message. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign

You can verify the signature with `ecrecover` in Solidity. Have a look at this answer for examples: [ecrecover from Geth and web3.eth.sign](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/ecrecover-from-geth-and-web3-eth-sign)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by [Signing and Validating](https://medium.com/@angellopozo/ethereum-signing-and-validating-13a2d7cb0ee3). If someone signs a message with his private key, you can check that the public key belongs to that person by validating the signed message with it.

> **What is Signing?**
>
> Signing is the act of a user A “signing” data that anyone can validate came from user A. This is used in transactions to check if they are real.
>
> [...]
>
> Instead of real-world signatures, which can be faked, the digital ones can not. If you want to know user A did something, make them sign it before moving forward. Then if a dispute arises, check the signature.

You can sign using `web3.eth.sign` and validate signatures in solidity using `ecrecover`, as said by Rob Hitchens in this question. This is also explained in depht in the linked blog post.