# Can I use a Bitcoin client to sign a message with an Ethereum address?

Tags: bitcoin, signature, hd-wallets

If an Ethereum address is a point on the Bitcoin EC, then one can use the private key that matches that address to sign a message using bitcoin software.

I'd like someone to prove they have the private key for an ethereum address by signing something with it and I don't know how one would sign a message with an ethereum address.  I found https://etherscan.io/verifySig where such a signature can be verified.

If I export the private key for my ethereum address and then import it into a Bitcoin client and then sign a message with it, will that be valid according to etherscan's verifySig page?

If I simply restore my wallet to a Bitcoin client using my Bip39 phrase, then can I sign something with the bitcoin address at a certain derivation path to produce a valid signature under ethereum for the address at the same derivation path?

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/verifying-bicoin-signed-message-in-ethereum-smart-contract. An important difference is that bitcoin uses sha256 as hash function for signatures, and ethereum uses keccak256. It should be possible to verify signatures, but you will have to write some code to account the different hash functions used.